# How to get the proper return type when using a filter based on type in Scala

Tags: scala, filter, type-inference, scala-collections

The following doesn't compile. Do I need to cast the person first?

```
 object People {
  def all = List(
    new Person("Jack", 33),
    new Person("John", 31) with Authority,
    new Person("Jill", 21),
    new Person("Mark", 43)
  )
}

class Person(val name: String, val age: Int) 

trait Authority {
  def giveOrder {
    println("do your work!")
  }
}

object Runner {
  def main(args:List[String]) {
    val boss = People.all.find { _.isInstanceOf [Authority] }.get
    boss.giveOrder // This line doesnt compile
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add the compiler error. `Boss` is missing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're right thinking that somehow, there should be a mechanism that lets you avoid casting. Such a cast would be ugly and redundant, as it already appears in the filter anyway. `find`, however, does not care at all about the shape of the predicate it gets; it just applies it and returns an `Option[A]` if `A` is the static type of the collection's elements.

What you need is the `collect` function:

```
val boss = People.all.collect { case boss: Authority => boss }.head
```

`collect` creates a new collection. If you want to avoid this (if you're really only interested in the first element which is of kind `Authority`) in case of a potentially very long list of potential bosses, you may want to switch to a `view` to have it evaluated lazily:

```
val boss = People.all.view.collect { case boss: Authority => boss }.head
```

Finally, unless you're absolutely sure that there is always at least one boss in your list, you should really test whether or not the search was successful, e.g. like this:

```
val bossOpt = People.all.view.collect { case boss: Authority => boss }.headOption
bossOpt.foreach(_.giveOrder) // happens only if a boss was found
```

**Edit:** Finally, if you're using Scala 2.9, you should definitely use `collectFirst` as explained in [Kevin Wright's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933660/how-to-get-the-proper-return-type-when-using-a-filter-based-on-type-in-scala/5933988#5933988).

Comment: Furthermore, if you want to treat the boss instances as a Person as well, you can use this collect statement instead: `case boss:Person with Authority => boss`.

Comment: Wasn´t that aware of using `foreach` on `Option`. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Jean-Philippe's answer is good, but it's possible to go one step further...

If using Scala 2.9, you'll also have a `collectFirst` method available, allowing you to avoid all those tedious `view`'s, `head`'s and `headOption`'s

```
val boss = People.all.collectFirst { case x: Authority => x }
boss.foreach(_.giveOrder) // happens only if a boss was found
```

`boss` is still an `Option[Person]`, I recommend that you keep it this way for the sake of safer code.  If you want, you can also use a for-comprehension, which some people to be cleaner still:

```
for(boss <- People.all.collectFirst { case x: Authority => x }) {
  boss.giveOrder // happens only if a boss was found
}
```

Comment: +1 Cool, didn't know about `collectFirst`. It fits most perfectly here.

Comment: Not surprising, it isn't yet in a stable release of the language (close though, we're already on RC4 at the time of writing)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
boss.asInstanceOf[Authority].giveOrder
```

or this

```
val boss =  People.all.find { _.isInstanceOf [Authority] }.get.asInstanceOf[Person with Authority]
```

Comment: Didn't downvote myself, but I imagine it's due to the use of `isInstanceOf` (frequently a code smell) instead of pattern matching with `collect`

Comment: `isInstanceOf`, `asInstanceOf`, `Option.get` are all not very pretty…

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to find just the first one? `find` does exactly this. Consider using the solution from Jean-Philippe if you want to find all `Authority`s:

```
val authorities = People.all.collect {
  case boss: Authority => boss
}.foreach(_.giveOrder)
```